# efs ResourceInitializationError on ECS-Fargate tasks

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

getting the below error when i try to mount efs volume on my fargate task

> Task stopped at: 2024-02-06T18:26:28.433Z
> ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: Failed to resolve
> "fs-0xxxxxxxxxf.efs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file
> system ID is correct, and ensure that the VPC has an EFS mount target
> for this file system ID. See
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/efs/mount-dns-name for more
> detail. Attempting to lookup mount target ip address using botocore.
> Failed to import necessary dependency botocore, please install
> botocore first. : unsuccessful EFS utils command execution; code: 1

i have checked

1. EFS file system mount target isr available in an Availability Zone where Fargate tasks are launched.
2. The VPC DNS hostnames turned on
3. file system ID is correct

all security groups and subnets that im using are correctly configured.
checked by instaling botocore in my image this also gives the same error

**one key point to be noted is this image works fine in testing stage but dosent work in prod stage**